# How to sign the JWT with Elliptic Curve in Spring Boot Oauth (spring-security-jwt)?

Tags: spring-security, spring-security-oauth2

I used `ssh-keygen -t ecdsa -b 521` to [create a sample EC key pair](https://www.ssh.com/ssh/keygen/). I then tried hooking that into the spring oauth flow but I was unable to figure it out.

There exists [org.springframework.security.jwt.crypto.sign.EllipticCurveVerifier](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security-oauth/blob/master/spring-security-jwt/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/jwt/crypto/sign/EllipticCurveVerifier.java) but there's no EC Signer. In addition, I couldn't find examples on creating ECPublicKey and ECPrivateKey from a static EC key-pair in String form.

The RSA support for signing JWTs is straightforward. The classes org.springframework.security.jwt.crypto.sign.RsaSigner and RsaVerifier make it super easy to sign and verify tokens with a static RSA key pair in String form. I was expecting something similar. Am I missing something?

*Update*

I don't think it's supported even with custom implementations of Signer and SignatureVerifier - https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security-oauth/blob/master/spring-security-jwt/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/jwt/JwtAlgorithms.java#L30-L34

You cannot use JwtHelper class as supported algos are hard-coded.

I wonder what the EC* classes were supposed to do if the ecdsa is not supported?